# how to show complete List and vertically inside of report JasperReport from java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I've the fowolling fileds from datasource building in java

[image]

Where  *archivosEncontrados* is a List so a get following  when building the report:

[image]

You can see above that the the list began with the symbol ***[***.

But I can not see the complete list. So I try other thing

I put a List element inside of report and settup the following way:

double click in the *dataset* -> Edit Query->JavaBean DataSource, in the field class I put the name of my class and click in reat atributtes and I select the field that containt  the list, it's mean I chose *archivosEncontrados*
[image]

And I edit the expression of datasource and I put

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{archivosEncontrados})
```

But when I show the report I cant see the list.

So what can I do to show the list vertically and complete?

I expected some like:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I've a list inside of bean, it's mean that I've a collection of beans that it have a list.

So, find the answers to: [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300/jrbeancollectiondatasource-how-to-show-data-from-the-java-util-list-from-javabe)

But when I try to make it, I get following mistake:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'archivosEncontrados' on class 'class java.lang.String'
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1322)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
... 60 more

oct 29, 2013 6:48:47 AM co.gov.rnec.srcw.business.reporte.ListadoConsultaController exportar
SEVERE: null
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean :   archivosEncontrados
```

this is the jrxhml: https://gist.github.com/cristianchaparroa/4f4289fb04d3c44cc9d2

what do I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should put attribute of object from list in detail band. It will iterate all value from list.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain with code  or images?