# jaspersoft how to display values from list

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using iReport 5 to generate PDF. I got few lists containing some objects to display, and it's the easy part. I got stuck on displaying values from `List<String>`. 
I pass it as a parameter, I configured data source correctly, but have no idea how to name the string. 
When I got list of objects it's easy - if you want to get field xxx from obcject you use `$F{xxx}` and it works, but how to display a object? I tried `$F{_this}`, but got error saying that it's non recognizable.

Comment: Is this the same situation you are describing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300/jrbeancollectiondatasource-how-to-show-data-from-the-java-util-list-from-javabe

Comment: kinda. I see that it's not that easy to pass simple data. They used wrapper, and so I did now. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Creating a field called _THIS should work.

Comment: so close, yet I already used wrapping object. But I tested your solution - it works.