# Passing an ArrayList report shows comma every item

Tags: java, arraylist, jasper-reports

I'm passing an List of String to JasperReports report via parameter.

```
String jasperFileName = "C:\\TestReportProcess.jasper";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("List", getMyListOfString());
JasperPrint jprint = (JasperPrint) asperFillManager.fillReport(jasperFileName, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

when report starting it shows comma every item

```
item 1,
item 2,
item 3,
item 4,
etc etc
```

How can avoid it?

My jasper report xml

```
        <parameter name="List" class="java.util.ArrayList" isForPrompting="false"/>
        <detail>
            <band height="280" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="13" width="550" height="45" uuid="f907894e-e9f1-418b-9ab8-1db276b8482e"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font fontName="Antique Olive Compact"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{List}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

This is my simple xml report, there is just a parameter as java.util.Arraylist

Comment: You should post your *jrxml* file

Comment: Alex updated with jrxml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing the List of primitive type objects as datasource for subreport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949333/passing-the-list-of-primitive-type-objects-as-datasource-for-subreport) & [How do I print a list of strings contained within another list in iReport?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1771864/876298) & [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12209300/876298)

Comment: You should pass convert List to datasource

Comment: i have seen some your example. Do i have to use only a JavaBean or can pass just a arraylist<String> to datasource??????

Comment: You can use a `List<String>`

Comment: The same question as your: [jaspersoft how to display values from list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23151030/876298)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the *`List<String>`* in several ways:

1. Passing *`List<String>`* as parameter and use this parameter in *subDataset* (in *dataSourceExpression*)
2. Passing  *`List<String>`* as *JRDataSource* with help of *[JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html#JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Collection))*
3. Converting *`List<String>`* to the *String* object and replace comma into carriage return (*\n*) or just remove comma with help of *String.replace* method.

### Example

The example shows both approaches

#### Java code

We populating ***listOfItems*** parameter with *`List<String>`* and fill report with *JRBeanCollectionDataSource*.

```
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6"));

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("listOfItems", Arrays.asList("Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"));
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
```

#### Report template

The datasource contains *6* items (elements) for showing in *Detail* band (main dataset).

Parameter *listOfItems* contains the list of *3* elements to show in *Title* band with help of *subDataset* of *Table* component.

The *Summary* band is used to show how to show data from *`List<String>`*  (*listOfItems* parameter) with just one *textField* element.

The *fieldDescription* help us to get the field's value. With help of *_THIS* keyword we getting the *String* value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Passing List of String" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <subDataset name="listDataset">
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="listOfItems" class="java.util.List"/>
    <field name="item" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="27">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="200" height="15">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="listDataset">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{listOfItems})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="200">
                        <jr:detailCell height="15">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="15"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{item}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="100" height="15" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfItems}.toString().replace(",", " ").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="300" y="40" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{listOfItems}.toString().replace(", ", "\n").replace("[", "").replace("]", "")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The usage of *[List.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString())* method gives result like this: *`[val1, val2]`* - values separated with comma and enclosed in square brackets. The usage of *String.replace* method (several serial calling of this method) give us nice results.

#### Output result

The generated *pdf* file with help of *JRPdfExporter* looks like:

[image: Generated pdf]