# Get current element from a dataset in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

Given I have a simple List that I pass to a table and I'd like to do some calculation on the list elements so I wrote a scriptlet for it but I have to pass the current element to it. Can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300/jrbeancollectiondatasource-how-to-show-data-from-the-java-util-list-from-javabe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out thanks to [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/528427/iterate-through-arryalist-jrxml) post. Basically you just have to create a field with name _THIS on the dataset of the table.