# JasperReports: List object getting merged with other object list while generating report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Am not experienced much in JasperReports but this is my second assignment and am stuck with this issue

Below is my Java bean classes Report and ReportRecords,

```
Class Report{
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private String field4;
    List<ReportRecords> reportRecordData = new ArrayList<>();

    ....setters getters()....
}

Class ReportRecords{
    private String column1;
    private String column2;
    private String column3;
    private String column4;

    ....setters getters()....
}
```

And i am exporting report like below,

```
    List<Report> report = getReports();

    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(report);
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    JasperPrint printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReport(template, parameters, beanColDataSource);
    JRTextExporter txtExporter = new JRTextExporter();

    txtExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.LINE_SEPARATOR, "\r\n");
    txtExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_WIDTH, 110);
    txtExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.PAGE_HEIGHT, 80);
    txtExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, printFileName);
    txtExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "C:/report/report.txt");
    txtExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_WIDTH,new Float(7));
    txtExporter.setParameter(JRTextExporterParameter.CHARACTER_HEIGHT,new Float(13));
    txtExporter.exportReport();
```

And below is the Jasper code, i removed other label related code and added only necessary code here,

```
<subDataset name="serviceCodeData" uuid="6b6aa9cd-83d1-47b6-b475-2988e1a3a804">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="column1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="column2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="column3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="column4" class="java.lang.String"/>
</subDataset>
<field name="Field1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Field2" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Field3" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Field4" class="java.lang.String"/>

<pageHeader>
    <!-- All Field1 to Field4 labels and values -->
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <!-- All column1 to column2 labels -->
</columnHeader>

    And below is the list for column values

<detail>
    <band height="19" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="-19" y="0" width="818" height="19" uuid="d08327de-369c-41b5-818a-2381d0f7def2"/>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                <datasetRun subDataset="reportRecordData" uuid="f39ce5d6-7347-4911-b211-3c60cbd01590">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{reportRecordData})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="19" width="818">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="39" y="0" width="157" height="18" uuid="03ef5ad6-fafb-4c5d-aa41-a46b1474f9fd"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{column1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="39" y="0" width="157" height="18" uuid="03ef5ad6-fafb-4c5d-aa41-a46b1474f9fd"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{column2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="39" y="0" width="157" height="18" uuid="03ef5ad6-fafb-4c5d-aa41-a46b1474f9fd"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{column3}}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="39" y="0" width="157" height="18" uuid="03ef5ad6-fafb-4c5d-aa41-a46b1474f9fd"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{column4}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
```

And the report supposed tobe generated like below,

[image]

But it is generating as below, its merging all List to one Report object,

[image]

Please ask if any other details needed regarding this, help me.

Comment: you can have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300/jrbeancollectiondatasource-how-to-show-data-from-the-java-util-list-from-javabe). See if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of Jasper Reports is to first generate the `pageHeader`, `columnHeader` (called once on each page) and then to iterate the `detail` band on your datasource.

This is why you are having the current result. The `pageHeader`, `columnHeader` is create when you are at record one, then the list in detail band is called twice on your datasource.

You should to move `Report, Field1,.. Field4` **into the detail band**, so also these are displayed as datasource is iterated.