# Add custom data source to Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to fill a table by passing a custom data source to it.
I have created a simple report with a table on it. The report it self gets the data from a ms sql database. I have written a java class similar to the class in this [Example](http://www.javaquery.com/2015/11/how-to-fill-jasper-table-using.html). But I get no value in table. At the example there is no scriptlet. I have checked the `(String) this.getFieldValue("KN_FormelGG");`  line of code. It gets the data from field and can show it on report. So I guess the bean data source is not filled. I call the fill Table method in a `afterGroupInit`. How can I use Collection of data from java in jasper? I tried also adding the java bean in **dataset and query dialog**, but it did not help me either. Should I add the scriptlet to subreport/table? The main emphasis of my problem having the custom data source in a scriptlet. I went the [other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300) through, but I still get no answer. I added `$P{FieldDataSource}.getData()` to check the data, but it delivers null.

**java class 1:**

```
package testProjektIman.scriptlets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRScriptletException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class FillTable extends JRDefaultScriptlet {

    @Override
public void afterGroupInit(final String id)
        throws JRScriptletException {
    fillTable();
}
public ArrayList<String> splitGGArray(final String kNFormelGG) {
    ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] array = (kNFormelGG.split(" "));
    for (String sub : array) {
        fieldNames.add(sub);
    }
    return fieldNames;
}

public Map<String, Object> fillTable()
        throws JRScriptletException {
    String kNFormelGG = null;
    kNFormelGG = (String) this.getFieldValue("KN_FormelGG");
    List<TableCells> listTableCells = new ArrayList<>();
    TableCells tableCell;
    for (String fn : splitGGArray(kNFormelGG)) {
        tableCell = new TableCells();
        tableCell.setFieldName(fn);
        listTableCells.add(tableCell);
    }
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource tableCellJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listTableCells);
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("FieldDataSource", tableCellJRBean);
    return parameters;
}

}
```

**Java class 2**

```
package testProjektIman.scriptlets;
public class TableCells {
private String fieldName;
private String keyFormel;
private String mK;
private String notation;
private String Item;
//getters setters
}
```

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="tableAutoFill" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="37fc3a9c-38e9-41be-9039-56249c5283d7">
    <subDataset name="TableDataSource" uuid="5999e646-aeec-4b2b-b29b-68e897d56999">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="fieldName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <scriptlet name="Filltable" class="testProjektIman.scriptlets.FillTable"/>
    <parameter name="FieldDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from "KennzahlReferenz2015_QIBericht",  "Images" 
where LB_ID =  62
and KN_OffiziellGruppe =  3
and  IMG_ID = 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="KN_Id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="KN_FormelZ" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="KN_FormelGG" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="id">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{KN_Id}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50"/>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="191" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="50" y="18" width="260" height="120" uuid="942ab836-df83-4a2f-8215-845073ad163f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="TableDataSource" uuid="b554ada5-c388-4534-af8e-93571a417adb">
                        <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{FieldDataSource}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{FieldDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="f57e4e8e-8a2e-405f-b9ab-7a704e0986fd">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="9a55dd73-71e3-4559-9a8b-17d98bf17753"/>
                                <textElement>
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[FieldName]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="c3e6ccfc-9f91-4d7a-800a-613f5dded928"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fieldName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300/jrbeancollectiondatasource-how-to-show-data-from-the-java-util-list-from-javabe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Data Adapter

Create a data adapter file, for example `adapter.xml`, through the user interface. The contents might resemble:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beanDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.bean.BeanDataAdapterImpl">
    <name>YourClass</name>
    <factoryClass>com.yourcompany.jasper.JRDataSourceFactory</factoryClass>
    <methodName>createCollection</methodName>
    <useFieldDescription>false</useFieldDescription>
</beanDataAdapter>
```

## Data Class

Create a class that has a `createCollection` method, as per the data adapter definition above:

```java
package com.compay.jasper;

public class JRDataSourceFactory {
    /**
     * @return A collection of data for the report.
     */
    public static Collection<YourClass> createCollection() {
        return Arrays.asList( new YourClass() );
    }
}
```

## Set Report Properties

Ensure that the report has the following property (links the report to the custom data adapter):

```xml
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="adapter.xml"/>
```

## Set Report Fields

The report fields should now be able to reference the bean properties:

```xml
<field name="yourObject.property" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[yourObject.property]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

It's important that the `fieldDescription` element contain a value that reflects the bean property (i.e., the Java code you would normally call to retrieve the value from the bean on an instance of that bean).

## Application

The `JRDataSourceFactory` class stands alone -- it's used by the data adapter to create a collection of bean instances. The `static` method (`createCollection`) does the work here and does not, indeed cannot, use inheritance.

## Example

If possible, borrow the field names for the report from the bean's attributes. The code as written in the question makes it difficult to discern where the value for `KN_Id` comes from.

The following example links the data adapter to the field names in the report.

### Bean Class

A bean exposes some properties:

```java
package com.company.domain;

public final class Student extends Entity {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }
}
```

### Data Adapter

The data adapter looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beanDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.bean.BeanDataAdapterImpl">
    <name>Student</name>
    <factoryClass>com.company.jasper.JRDataSourceFactory</factoryClass>
    <methodName>createCollection</methodName>
    <useFieldDescription>false</useFieldDescription>
</beanDataAdapter>
```

### Data Class

The data class creates instances of the bean:

```java
package com.compay.jasper;

import com.company.domain.Student;

public class JRDataSourceFactory {
    public static Collection<Student> createCollection() {
        return Arrays.asList( new Student() );
    }
}
```

### Report Fields

The report fields reflect the bean fields:

```xml
<field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

A collection of "student" instances is passed into the report. In this example, the collection contains a single instance. In your example, the collection could contain many instances. As the report library iterates over the collection, different values of `firstName` and `lastName` will be made available.

The mechanics for how the `Student` instance data is initially populated is outside the scope of this answer. As far as the reporting tool is concerned, it simply uses pre-populated instances of `Student`. If `FillTable` populates `TableCells`, that's not a concern for the reporting tool.