# Printing Collection of Strings on Different Pages using iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to print a Collection parameter on different pages using iReport by passing a String array into iReport from Java.

However, when I tried to print the Collection parameter, the report reflected [String1, String2, String3] after I generated the report. I would like the report to print String 1 on Page 1, String 2 on Page 2 and so on. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Show us how your report is currently. You can post the .jrxml then we can load it up and see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300/jrbeancollectiondatasource-how-to-show-data-from-the-java-util-list-from-javabe)