# How to Display Child Class pass into Jasper Report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I hope someone can help me to fix my problem. I am creating a report where it needs to show its child class. **Person -> History**. This is what i did so far:

```
            if(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Personal Data Sheet")){
                String reference = "";
                String name = "";
                String homeAddress = "";
                String dob = "";
                ...

                if(application != null){
                    reference = application.getReference();
                    name = application.getApplicant() != null ? application.getApplicant().getCompleteName() : "";
                    homeAddress = application.getApplicant() != null 
                            && !application.getApplicant().getHomeAddress().isEmpty() 
                            ?  application.getApplicant().getHomeAddress().isEmpty() : "";
                    ...
                }
                try {
                    //JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(datasource);
                    List<Map<String, Object>> datasource = new ArrayList<>();

                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("field1", reference);
                    map.put("field2", name);
                    map.put("field3", homeAddress);
                    ...

                    HistoryService hisService = new HistoryServiceImpl();
                    if(hisService.findHistoryByReference(reference) != null){
                        for(History his: hisService.findHistoryByReference(reference)){
                            map.put("hisNam", his.getName());
                            map.put("hisDesc", his.getDescritpion());
                        }
                    }

                    ...
                    datasource.add(map);

                    JRDataSource jRDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(datasource);
                    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(new File("")
                            .getAbsolutePath() + "/src/org/project120/report/PDSReport.jrxml");
                    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

                    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, jRDataSource);
                    JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
                    jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
                ...
```

My problem arises with my **for loop**. upon viewing the Report generated it only displays the last item on the list. I looked for other solution online and most of it uses subreport but it use with **direct connection (query)**. In my case i am using **empty data set**.

My desire output is somehing like:

```
Personal Data Sheet Reference: 12345
Name: Jhon D. Doe
Home Address: Sample Address
Background History(ies):
     History 1   This is history 1
     History 2   This is history 2
     ...
```

**Thank you very much in advance for any help**

Comment: So, is the "history" information setup as a subreport?

Comment: I did not yet implement the code and i think this where i get lost, but i already created its subreprt layout.

Comment: By the way sir, how would I setup the child class as subreport?

Comment: Well, from the dusts of my memory, a subreport would need a `List` of objects

Comment: Duplicates: [JRBeanCollectionDataSource: How to show data from the java.util.List from JavaBean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12209300/876298)